# jQuery works on jsFiddle but not in a live page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, jsfiddle

**THE QUESTION**

Interesting one that probably has a simple solution. With the help of @jessegavin I've added a jQuery function to my page that controls the playback of HTML5 audio elements on the page. The code is beautiful and works correctly on a jsFiddle, but not when put into the context of my page.

I've thrown time to the wind and methodically stepped through this to try and isolate my mistake, but with no avail. Really, I went Aristotle on this one and applied the scientific method. Please forgive me for the heft of this question. It's really my last resort.

**THE NITTY GRITTY**

Here are my findings: All the JavaScript functions for the page work correctly in context of the jsFiddle. After specifically adding the functions one at a time I can say that they each work appropriately, and that all except for the HTML5 audio playback work on both the jsFiddle and the live page. That is to say ONLY the HTML5 audio playback is not working on the live page.

All the HTML is 100% validated, all the CSS is 100% validated. Both groups are code are added into the jsFiddle in their entirety.

The page heading loads (in this order) an external CSS document, jQuery 1.5.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.8 (same on jsFiddle, except for UI, which is 1.8.9) via Google's onload command, an external JavaScript document (where ALL functions for the site reside), and finally a Google Analytics function.

The JavaScript is wrapped in a document ready framework.

My guess is that the discrepancy lies somewhere in the head, but I cant imagine what exactly it is. All the external links work correctly, evidenced by the JavaScript functions working correctly (except for the new audio controller).

**THE POST SCRIPT**

P.S.- Only works in Chrome and Safari as of yet.. The server I'm hosting the two audio files off of doesn't have the correct ht-access file declaring OGG as a correct MIME type. I'll start a question for that too.

**RESOURCES**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66FwR/3/

**HTML** (heading only, body is in jsFiddle)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name="description" content="Fernando Garibay- Producer, Songwriter, Artist, Multi-Instrumentalist, and Programmer" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Fernando Garibay, Music, Producer, Songwriter, Artist, Mutli-Instrumentalist, Programmer." />
<title>Fernando Garibay - Music</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.fernandogaribay.com/favicon.ico" />
<link href="../styles/fernando.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAqfg-jHFfaMB9PWES0K_8ChTCwkclEZER8BG2IP57SKkFV1O9hxSZkzKYPDs-3mbhEluKXjbKUAB7sQ"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.5.1");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.8");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/fernando.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--Copyright 2011, Fernando Garibay, Inc-->
<!--Developed by Minimal +-->
</head>
<body onload="message()">
```

**JavaScript** (the function that works on jsFiddle, but not in a live page)

```
 $(function() {
     $(".playback").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);
         if (song.paused)
         song.play();
       else
         song.pause();
     });
 });
```

Comment: there may b `jQuery conflict` problem..what error u r getting??

Comment: @diEcho. No specific errors; I'm not seeing the result of the audio control function when it's live in the page. It's proven functional in the jsFiddle.. and that's in the context of the entire sites JavaScript.

Comment: @diEcho. Yes, the audio tag's playback should be controlled by the above function. It works on jsFiddle, but not in context of the live page.

Comment: *but not when put into the context of my page* -- you have to tell us what happens; is there a javascript error or does the video not play at all. Open up the console (F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+J), note down any javascript errors and paste them along with your question.

Comment: @Salman on a Mac running Chrome.. Is that a Firefox reference?

Comment: f12 if you have firefox with firebug or ie8+. ctrl+shift+j works in chrome and firefox without firebug.

Comment: @Salman cmd-opt-j for Chrome on a Mac... No JavaScript errors reported other than no fancy box element, but that's for a different page. There's no audio playback in the live page, but there is on jsFiddle.

Comment: FYI: I cannot get it to work in FF 3.6 (the jsFiddle example does not work at all, yet `typeof $("audio")[0].paused` returns boolean and `typeof $("audio")[0].play` returns function as expected. I WORKS in Chrome. Is it that that the browser does not support ogg/mp3 playback? In FF i get "download this file" prompt when I manually enter the ogg/mp3 URL in the address bar.

Comment: @Salman A The server I'm hosting the files off of doesn't have an ht-access file declaring OGG as a valid MIME type. Another feat to tackle.. If I can get this method working. For now, Chrome and Safari support it and prove that theoretically it's a viable direction.

Comment: Have you already tried matching the jsFiddle environment (UI 1.8.9)? Also try removing the Google loader and just including jquery and UI in the traditional manner.

Comment: @shanethehat definitely. Even sourced the jsFiddle off of Google's hosted libraries. Besides.. the other functions wouldn't work if the libraries didn't load.

Comment: @shanethehat here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/66FwR/5/

Comment: Can you provide a link to the version that doesn't work as well?

Comment: @shanethehat http://minimalpluscreative.com/newclients/dev/fernandogaribay/music/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two JavaScript errors on your live page (in both Chrome and Firefox):

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: message is not defined`

You reference fancybox() in fernando.js, and message in the `<body onload="message()">`. Those errors are most likely stopping your audio control code from running.

Comment: YES. Pulled those out of one version and not another. I knew I missed something. How can I give you more kudos??

Comment: All in a day's work, is all. Firebug and the Web Inspector are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is http://fiddle.jshell.net/66FwR/3/show/ look at that.
It includes jQuery UI too. You could copy the source and use that.